# Operator overloading confusion

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, decrement, unary-operator

I know there have been many questions posted about operator overload, but I can't get my code to work with any of the examples I find. Yes, I have taken a look at  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading), but I am still having trouble understanding this.

I am trying to overload just the prefix operator, but I get an error saying that postfix expects an int. I am NOT trying to modify the postfix operator.
I have a .h file, and a .cpp file. Inside of my .h file I have something like:

```
class X{
public:
        /* ... declarations of X ... */
        X& operator--(X& x);
};
```

And inside of my .cpp file I have something like:

```
#include "X.h"
namespace X{
X& X::operator--(X& x){/*...*/}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you show an example of trying to use your function and the exact compiler error.

Comment: Personally I avoid operator overloading as it more trouble than it is worth

Comment: Why does the cpp file have class X's member functions in the X namespace?  That's not the case in the header file.

Comment: Here's a good example http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/97-overloading-the-increment-and-decrement-operators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prefix `--` operator takes no arguments. Its definition should be as follows:

```
public:
    /* ... declarations of X ... */
    X& operator--();
};
```

And similarly when implementing it:

```
#include "X.h"
namespace X {
    X& X::operator--() {/*...*/}
}
```

Comment: OK, this makes more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> X& operator--(X& x);
> ```

Must be:

```
X& operator--();
```

---

Background: The compiler sees that you've given your `--` operator an argument. The postfix version of `--` takes an argument, so it thinks you mean that one. But the type of that argument must by convention be `int`. So it tells you exactly that: `postfix 'X& X::operator--(X&)' must take 'int' as its argument`.

The compiler *could* also tell you something like `prefix 'X& X::operator--(X&)' must not take any argument` if it wanted to. But, oh well. That's the way it is. Producing any diagnostic message is enough to conform to the C++ standard.